# Punch him good?

Tags: adverbs

I some time ago saw some sentences, *"Punch him good", "You punch really good"*. I assume, that good works as adverb and means *well*. Upon assuming, I got a question: How has the word *good* become to mean *well*? Why do people occasionally use *good* instead of *well*?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually, people encouraging someone to punch someone else aren't of the predisposition to use the more proper, higher register *"well"*. **Punch 'em good, Walter!** Sounds so much more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it seems as though *good* and *well* are used interchangeably sometimes - that's not really the case:

***"Punch him good,"*** comes from the expression to *give (somebody) a* ***good punch.*** In part, we are referring to "a punch, well administered," but there is an additional meaning which is: "A well administered punch would certainly do (said person) some *good*." Hence, a ***"good punch"*** and ***"Punch him good"***.

***"You punch really good,"*** is simply wrong.

When you ask someone, "How are you?", the standard answer is: "Very ***well***, thank you." But, let's say this person has a terrible cold... It is unlikely that they will say that they are "very well".

However, if they answer you: *"I'm* ***good***, *thank you,"* they may be letting you know that they have their box of tissues and are well medicated, and their favorite show is on TV. So, *"good"* in this case, is short for the expression, ***"good to go"*** (prepared to face the situation).